# Default folder icons missing after user account rename

Tags: macos, finder, user-account, folders, icon

I started using a MacBook Air M1, macOS Big Sur 11.2. When I created the user account I selected a lowercase name for the home directory. Later, I wanted to change that to a first uppercase name. I found and used instructions for that (log in as a different user, rename directory, modify account info to point to the right directory). All of this worked fine; I can log in without problems, all files and foldes are there.

However - in Finder, all top level folders in my home directory now have the generic folder icon. No special icons for Documents, Music, Movies, Pictures, Downloads, Desktop, Public.

How do I restore those?

Any help appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had never modified account info correctly. It still indicated the lower case directory as home dir - and that worked since the file system is not case sensitive. No more help needed.

Comment: Great! I would encourage you to mark your question as answered in that case :)

Comment: Thanks - rookie mistake. But it seems like there's a timer on that. I need to wait another 13 hours.